# Forcing Thread to execute an operation every day at specific time

Tags: java, multithreading

As part of an assignment to build a coupon system
I'm working on an assignment to build a Java program to support coupon system database.
I'm supposed to create a Thread that runs a task at the beginning of every day (00:00:00 or a bit later) that checks which of the coupons in the database expired and removes them from database. For this I can't use java libs and packages that implement schedulers and timers.
I'm struggling to find a way to assure that the task runs every day at the specific time it needs to be.

Here is what I came up with till now (it will only work in 24 hours intervals):

```
    public class DailyCouponExpirationTask extends Thread {

        // class fields
        private boolean keepRunning;
        private final long sleepTime;
        private CompanyDBDAO companyDBDAO;
        private CouponDBDAO couponDBDAO;
        private CustomerDBDAO customerDBDAO;

        // constructor
        DailyCouponExpirationTask() {
            keepRunning = true;
            this.sleepTime = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            companyDBDAO = new CompanyDBDAO();
            couponDBDAO = new CouponDBDAO();
            customerDBDAO = new CustomerDBDAO();
        } // end constructor

        // class methods
        // force the thread to stop
        void stopRunning() {
            keepRunning = false;

            interrupt();
        } // end method stopRunning

        // Runnable interface methods
        // run 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (keepRunning) {
                Date currentDate = new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
                Collection<Coupon> coupons = couponDBDAO.getAllCoupons();

                Iterator<Coupon> iterator = coupons.iterator();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Coupon currentCoupon = iterator.next();

                    if (currentDate.after(currentCoupon.getEndDate())) {
                        // remove coupon from database
                    }
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    if (keepRunning) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } // end method run

    } // end class DailyCouponExpirationTask
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've come up with a solution and I would like to hear your thoughts and comments about it.
I'v created a method to calculate the overall sleep time of the `Thread` until next routine task iteration:

```
// calculate sleep time until next coupons update task (1:00:00 next day)
private long calculateSleepTime() {
    Calendar currentTime = new GregorianCalendar();
    Calendar nextUpdateTime = new GregorianCalendar();

    nextUpdateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
    nextUpdateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    nextUpdateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    nextUpdateTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    nextUpdateTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    return nextUpdateTime.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime.getTimeInMillis();
} // end method calculateSleepTime
```

Comment: You can use Spring batch to do this

Comment: why would cronTab or WindowsService (depending on O.S) would not work for u?

Comment: @MrunalGosar
Actually this is an assignment I was given. It supposed to run once in a day but I think it will be better if it will run during night time at the beginning of every day before users log to the system. For the assignment I'm not supposed to use external libs so I'm trying to figure out if it can be done using only basic Java.

Comment: you can use [Spring The @Scheduled Annotation with cron expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Date class, just use the substring method to get the day of the week and check if it is the same. if it is not then a new day has arrived.

Here is what your run method should look like:

```
public void run(){
 while(true){

   Date d=new Date();
 String day=d.toString().substring(0,3);
 for(;;){
try{
Thread.sleep(60000);
 Date date=new Date();
 String currentday=date.toString().substring(0,3);
 if(day.equals(currentday)==false){break;}
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
  Date d=new Date();

}
//Do things once a day
}
}
```

Hope this Helped:)

Comment: first, whiy would you use the 'for' loop for 'sleep' method and not just pass a milliseconds representing entire day?
second, from what I understand your code works in intervals of 24 hours but not in a specific time in the day as needed.

Comment: sleep doesn't release the resources. Is it good approach to keep a thread running forever?

Comment: @NitzanM Just Edited the answer.

Comment: @NitzanM No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can be 100% certain that a thread runs exactly at the specified time (it depends on a lot of factors like OS, system load, etc).
Having said that, take a look at [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) specifically at the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method. It provides an API to schedule an execution at periodic times. For example you can do:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    long initialDelay = 1800;
    long period = 3600;
    TimeUnit timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            //do something here
        }
    }, initialDelay, period, timeUnit);
```

What this does is, schedule a task to be executed after 1800 seconds and then repeated every 3600 seconds.
You have to keep in mind that for a scheduled action to execute, the JVM has to be kept running.

I highly recommend browsing the javadocs for the [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. You'll find a lot of goodies in there.

Comment: I'm aware that I can't know the exact time the Thread will execute his task, but a deviation of few minutes or so will meet the requirements. Thanks for your answer I will look in to it!